# cant get the type of a callExpr argument

Tags: llvm, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to get the type of a argument from a call expression to later use that type in a rewriter.
here's what i have:

```
const clang::Expr *const *FuncArgs = CallExpress.getArgs();

std::string QTString = FuncArgs[0]->getType().getBaseTypeIdentifier()->getName().str();
```

when I run this, it compiles and links fine but then when i run it i get a segmentaion fault.
turns this segmentation fault happens when i call `getName`.
my question are first, what am doing wrong? and if I'm going about this correcly. are there other ways of acquiring the QT from an argument in a callExpr?

Comment: Very likely that `getBaseTypeIdentifier` returns `nullptr`, which leads to the segfault.

Comment: i checked again. im fine with getName too. the problem starts when i call "str" to turn the StringRef into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. you could just call `getType` and then call `getAsString` to get the type as string given that you already have `FuncArgs` from the original question.

Comment: But `getAsString` returns `std::string`, `StringRef` would be better.